# vb.net Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary

Good Evening,

Does anyone have any idea I can do something like this in VB.net?

The problem I have is with declaring iDatabase as a Dictionary of iTable as it wants a class type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Colin

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Database As New iDatabase
        Dim Users = Database.Add("User", User)
        Users.Add(Guid.NewGuid, New User() With {.Username = "username"})
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class iDatabase
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, iTable)

    Public Class iTable(Of Entity As Class)
        Inherits Dictionary(Of Guid, Entity)

    End Class
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property Username As String
End Class
```

Comment: PS: The above code is more of a nice to have and not actual working code. I could do something like this but want to keep the type of value for the iTable dynamic:

Public Class iDatabase
Inherits Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Guid, iTable(Of User)))

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what you're trying to do. You have a couple of things in here that would prevent this from compiling. Could you provide some reasonings behind the `iTable` sub-class, whether you intend to use generics with type constraints, perhaps some additional usage. FYI a "dictionary of dictionaries" is easy enough (e.g. `As Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of Guid, User))`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have over-complicated this a bit. It looks like you want a "dictionary of dictionaries", where you have `"User"` as a key, and then under that key, another dictionary entry with a `Guid` key that maps to a `User`. In that case, you probably don't need to subclass `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` at all.

If you are going to have multiple classes (e.g. `Admin`, `User`), then you should use a common interface. Let's look at a complete example:

```
Public Interface IUser
    Property Username As String
End Interface

Public Class User Implements IUser
    Public Property Username As String Implements IUser.Username
End Class

Public Class Admin Implements IUser
    Public Property Username As String Implements IUser.Username
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim Database As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Guid, IUser))
    Database.Add("User", New Dictionary(Of Guid, IUser))
    Database("User").Add(Guid.NewGuid, New User() With {.Username = "username"})
    Database("User").Add(Guid.NewGuid, New Admin() With {.Username = "username"})
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cory. So what I want to do is a dictionary of iTables that are dictionaries of classes for example not just a User class but also say an Admin Class

Comment: @ColinTalbot: And how are `User` and `Admin` related? Is `Admin` a type of `User`? Or are they two different classes that each have a `Username` property?

Comment: Dim Database As New iDatabase
        Database.Add("User", User)
        Database("User").Add(Guid.NewGuid, New User() With {.Username = "user"})

        Database.Add("Admin", Admin)
        Database("User").Add(Guid.NewGuid, New User() With {.Username = "admin"})

Comment: I’m not sure if this is possible or if I should just create lists in the iDatabase class for the multiple “Entities”, the idea was to try and make it dynamic so I could add more iTables at runtime.

Comment: @Cory: In this specific example they would be two different classes.

Comment: If you created an interface (e.g. `IUser`) with a property `Username`, then `User` and `Admin` can both implement `IUser`, and in my example above, you would simply switch out the instances of `Dictionary(Guid, User)` for `Dictionary(Guid, IUser)`.

Comment: @ColinTalbot: I updated my answer to include the interface-based approach.

Comment: @Cory thanks again, what if the class had no common properties and some may have 20+ properties and others only 3 or 4? The Admin Class was a bad example but the idea was to keep it as dynamic as possible.

Comment: @ColinTalbot: You may have to explore other options: either keep an interface just for identification (an empty interface), and test/cast back to the correct class upon pulling the objects out, or, just use an `Object` for the second parameter. Without knowing the full scope of your intentions, it's hard to suggest a perfect solution. Generics can be tricky when you don't have objects that are actually related.